# LSTM vs. Hidden Layer Training in Tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, lstm

I am messing around with LSTMs and have a conceptual question. I created a matrix of bogus data on the following rules:

For each 1-D list in the matrix:

- If previous element is less than 10, then this next element is the previous one plus 1.
- Else, this element is sin(previous element)

This way, it is a sequence that is pretty simply based on the previous information.  I set up an LSTM to learn the recurrence and ran it to train on the lists one at a time.  I have an LSTM layer followed by a fully connected feed-forward layer.  It learns the +1 step very easily, but has trouble with the sin step.  It will seemingly pick a random number between -1 and 1 when making the next element when the previous one was greater than 10.  **My question is this**: is the training only modifying the variables in my fully connected feed forward layer? Is that why it can't learn the non-linear sin function?

Here's the code snippet in question:

```
lstm = rnn_cell.LSTMCell(lstmSize)
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, OS])

outputs, state = rnn.rnn(lstm, x, dtype=tf.float32)
outputs = tf.transpose(outputs, [1, 0, 2])
last = tf.gather(outputs, int(outputs.get_shape()[0]) - 1)

weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([lstmSize, OS]))
bias = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[OS]))

y = tf.nn.elu(tf.matmul(last, weights) + bias)
error = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.sub(y_, y)))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-3).minimize(error)
```

The error and shape organization seems to be correct, at least in the sense that it does learn the +1 step quickly without crashing.  Shouldn't the LSTM be able to handle the non-linear sin function? It seems almost trivially easy, so my guess is that I set something up wrong and the LSTM isn't learning anything.

Comment: Would you mind posting all the code? on a gist maybe?

Comment: The only other code that pertains to the LSTM is the training loop, which is the following:

`batch = data[startLocation:startLocation + 10];  

 output = getOutputInRange(data, startLocation + 1, startLocation + 11);  

 sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch, y_: output});`

The output is just the input offset by 1. The input/output strings come in groups of ten.

(I can't figure out how to do line breaks inside code in comments, sorry!)

Comment: What's your TensorFlow and CUDA version?

Comment: 0.8.0 and the most recent CUDA

Comment: To answer your question, no, the weights inside the lstm cell will also be updated during training. Something else is going wrong here.

Comment: Okay thank you. Interesting, though, because it's learning one step but not the other. Going to have to look deeper, I'll come back if I figure out what's going on.